# Philae Lander - Were drilling samples collected and analysed?

Tags: rosetta, comet, philae

Were drilling samples taken by SD2 and analysed by Ptolemy, COSAC, and ÇIVA?

Answer (score 9):

<s>Yes</s> No (see update). From [ESA's 15 November 2014 update on the Rosetta mission](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Rosetta/Pioneering_Philae_completes_main_mission_before_hibernation):

> **Pioneering Philae completes main mission before hibernation**
>
> `15 November 2014`
>
> Rosetta’s lander has completed its primary science mission after
>   nearly 57 hours on Comet 67P/Churyumov–Gerasimenko.
>
> After being out of communication visibility with the lander since
>   09:58 GMT / 10:58 CET on Friday, Rosetta regained contact with Philae
>   at 22:19 GMT /23:19 CET last night. The signal was initially
>   intermittent, but quickly stabilised and remained very good until
>   00:36 GMT / 01:36 CET this morning.
>
> In that time, the lander returned all of its housekeeping data, as
>   well as science data from the targeted instruments, including ROLIS,
>   COSAC, Ptolemy, SD2 and CONSERT. This completed the measurements
>   planned for the final block of experiments on the surface.
>
> ...

The article later mentions that the science teams are already studying this data to establish what type of cometary materials have been sampled with Philae's drill. Refer to [Rosetta blog](http://blogs.esa.int/rosetta/) for more up to date information as it is made available.

---

**Update**: Teams behind these mentioned Philae instruments also have their own Twitter feeds. Here's some (adding latest info):

- [Philae COSAC](https://twitter.com/Philae_COSAC) (Cometary Sampling and Composition Experiment); Latest tweets suggest **loss of subsurface data** despite attempting to drill through the hard crust in *desperate mode* (aka power mode 4 beyond design specs). The team concludes that *Surface must be >2 MPa hard!*.
- [MUPUS on Philae](https://twitter.com/Philae_MUPUS) (MUlti PUrpose Sensor); It links to just released [official DLR press release](http://www.dlr.de/dlr/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-10081/151_read-12176/year-all/#/gallery/17219).
- [Rosetta SD2](https://twitter.com/RosettaSD2) (Sample and Distribution Device)
- [Philae_ROMAP](https://twitter.com/Philae_ROMAP) (Rosetta Lander Magnetometer and Plasma Monitor)
- [Philae Ptolemy](https://twitter.com/Philae_Ptolemy) (gas chromatograph and medium resolution mass spectrometer)
- and of course [Philae Lander](https://twitter.com/Philae2014) and [ESA Rosetta Mission](https://twitter.com/ESA_Rosetta)

Rosetta's instruments also have their own Twitter feeds, such as [Rosetta MIDAS](https://twitter.com/RosettaMIDAS) or [Consert Rosetta](https://twitter.com/ConsertRosetta).

Comment: On Philae are there any sensors which could confirm that the drill was functional i.e. that the drill was rotating and applying sufficient force against the comet surface? (e.g. pulses from the motor, vibrations etc.)

Comment: @pabouk [Yes](https://twitter.com/Gizmodo/status/533408288671793152)

Comment: It is not yet clear whether the drilling was working correctly or not: _Because Philae was not anchored to the comet surface, it is also possible that, if the drill touched a particularly hard surface material, it moved the lander instead of drilling into the surface. Furthermore, the SD2 instrument lacks dedicated sensors to determine whether or not the surface has been reached, whether a sample was then collected in the sample tube, or if it was then discharged into the oven._ --- See [Did Philae drill the comet?](http://blogs.esa.int/rosetta/2014/11/19/did-philae-drill-the-comet/)

Answer (score 2):

Alas, no.  Reported today:

> [COSAC PI: Drill tried to deliver sample. Ovens heated up. But data
>   show no actual delivery. "There’s nothing in it."](https://twitter.com/erichand/status/534413817040867328)